# SolrJ 5.5.0 Query encodes the qf value (Query Fields) wrongly or not at all

Tags: java, encoding, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am facing a strange issue. Looks like a bug in the SolrJ API:

When I try to run a search query with edismax, the "qf" field is not being encoded properly.

I am trying to use this as my "**qf**" value:

**title^40+details_plain^20**

*SolrQuery.set()* method adds this to the query as it is which doesn't work as it needs to be url encoded.

When I url encode it myself, it becomes:

**qf=title%5E40+details_plain%5E20**

However when I set that in the query, the resulting final query automatically encodes it again and makes it:

**qf=title%255E40%2Bdetails_plain%255E20**

Which is also wrong and the query fails saying "undefined field text" because Solr doesnt know what I want to search for so it tried to search on the default "text" field.

Here is a snippet from the code:

```
SolrClient solr=null;
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

solr = new CloudSolrClient(zookeepers, "/" );
query.set("deftype", searchConfig.getDeftype());
    //query.set("df", "details_plain");  //unless i uncomment it the query fails as qf is not correct
query.set("fl", searchConfig.getFl());
query.set("mm", searchConfig.getMm());
query.set("qf", searchConfig.getQf());
query.set("rows", searchConfig.getRows());
query.set("q", searchPhrase);
query.set("collection", searchConfig.getCollection_name());
query.set("indent", "on");
query.set("omitHeader", "true");
query.set("wt", "json");
QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
```

Why doesn't it encode the original string, but encodes it again if I send it as an encoded string?

I might be overlooking something so let me know what you all think. Am I doing something wrong or should I just get Solr source code and try to fix this myself?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember you should not encode yourself any field. The encode/decode part is transparently handled by solrj.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Posting the solution here for anyone who might be unfortunate enough to have made the same silly mistake that I did.

The problem was in this line:

```
query.set("deftype", searchConfig.getDeftype());
```

the parameter name should be "defType" with a capital T instead of a small t like:

```
query.set("defType", searchConfig.getDeftype());
```

Ideally in such services parameter names should be all lowercase so as not to waste peoples time in issues like this but it is what it is. Maybe in a another SOLR version they will make the parameters name ignore case. One can hope!

Comment: In your question your're talking about an encoding problem, the answer is about a wrong parameter. Are you sure that this q/a make any sense? IMHO you should rewrite it enterely or delete it.